# I think this is python syntax inside my css file?

Tags: python, css, jinja2, hubspot

I've just taken on a hubspot project with an example theme.

I'm used to using scss and gulp, but inside the example css file I have variables like this

`{% set baseColor  = "#666" %}`

I know hubspot uses the Jinja2 templating system, this is my first time using it, but with this syntax inside my css file I can't pipe it through my gulp-scss module.

Is there a gulp module I can use to keep the jinja syntax and still use scss or am I going to have to use some other css preprocessor?

Comment: That's not python syntax. Python doesn't use `set` to assign variables.

Comment: @Barmar Oh okay, what is it? Flask, jinja2?

Comment: Hard to tell. Lots of different templating systems and frameworks use the same `{% ... %}` syntax. I'm not really familiar with any of them, so I don't know which have a `set` command.

Answer (score 0):

This is not python. It is HubL (http://designers.hubspot.com/docs/hubl/intro-to-hubl).